# write fails in same file from two processes

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

My Dll writes data into a file "Sample.txt".

If the Dll is loaded by two processes, then the Sample.txt will be written by both the processes.

In that case, only the process which writes first into file keeps on writing into it. I couldnt see the second process's data in that Sample.txt. I use Mutex for synchronizing between processes.

My code is as below,

```
HANDLE MLock = CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,L"MLock");
WaitForSingleObject(MLock,INFINITE);
ofstream fp;
fp.open("Sample.txt",ios::app);
fp <<  GetCurrentProcessID();
fp.close();
ReleaseMutex(MLock);
```

I can see only the first process's ID in the Sample.txt. Only if the first process gets killed the second process data is being written. Where am i going wrong?

Note: This issue occurs only in few machines.

Comment: Did you emit the error handling from your example? Note that `CreateMutex` can return `NULL`.

Comment: Also, `WaitForSingleObject` can return different results as well. You can check an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927(v=vs.85).aspx) for how to use Mutexes with `CreateMutex` and `WaitForSingleObject`

Comment: Although, I would probably recommend using [`lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) instead.

Comment: @Default lock_guard works inter-process? And just now checked , 'yes' i am getting NULL in CreateMutex. But GetLastError is not returning any error.

Comment: @Default Sorry for previous comment. GetLastError returns ACCESS_DENIED

Comment: If you are getting access denied from a createmutex call, then it is possible the calling processes are running in different sessions. Can your DLL be loaded from a service? or can the host machine be running remote as well as local logins, over something like RDP? I discuss this issue with mutexes on my site at http://www.bobmoore.dx.am/Win32/w32tip7.htm

Comment: I tried OpenMutex referring this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx . But Even that returned ACCESS_DENIED

Comment: @BobMoore This cannot be loaded as a service. and it should run in Local machine only. Starving for a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HANDLE MLock = CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,L"MLock");
if (NULL == MLock)
      MLock = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,L"MLock");

if (NULL == MLock){
   // error return 
}

WaitForSingleObject(MLock,INFINITE);
//...
```

Comment: Please check in the comments.! I tried that.. Even that gave me the same error

Comment: Yeah.. Seems Comments get hidden automatically if it grows :-/